# Should a non-Muslim write PBUH after the names of prophets and messengers?

Tags: salawat

I am a non-Muslim, atheist who writes on religion often.  I would like to be respectful towards Islam and Muslims.

I know that when Muslims write (in English) they put 'peace be upon him', 'PBUH', 'Allah's peace and blessings be upon him' or the Arabic for the same after the names of prophets.

As I am an atheist and not a Muslim, I do not believe in life after death or in Allah, and thus I do not think it is possible to wish for the wellbeing of the dead.  Thus, if I write 'PBUH', it is technically a lie (because I do not believe what I am saying).

I do not care about telling such a minor 'untruth'; I am very happy to add 'PBUH' after the Prophet's name.  It does not hurt me and I always want to be respectful.

However, I want to know: does Islam object to me making a 'false' wish (invoking Allah and the Prophet when I do not believe that either exist)?  Would it be better not to add 'PBUH' unless I truly believe in the 'PBUH'?  I just want to do whatever is most respectful towards Muslims and Islam!

Comment: There is no obligation in Deen. Even for Muslims, it is not Fard to write or say PBUH after the Prophet's name although it is a highly recommended Sunnah. Hence, as a non Muslim, no one expects you to follow the Islamic way of life. May Peace (Salam) be upon you too & if it is in your benefit may God guide you to His Mercy . Amen

Comment: @Ahmed We are [forbidden](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2167a) from greeting the non-Muslims with Assalamu 'Alaikum first.

Comment: @user2007 Thank you for the link but it has no tafseer on the Hadith... can you share the context in which it was instructed to do so. I'm sure the scholars of the past would have added commentary on the subject.

Comment: @Ahmed I can provide you a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVjGZdKmz78), and the student of knowledge (Sheikh 'Assim Al-Hakeem) gives fatwa of scholars, he doesn't give his own fatwa regarding an issue.

Comment: @user2007 Thank you for the link to the video. Unfortunately, Shiekh Assim doesn't give any reference (daleel) or tafseer in it.

Comment: @Ahmed Brother if you want more details regarding this you can visit [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/48966/greeting-a-kaafir-first). Although IslamQA maybe more strict in this regard than Shiekh 'Assim.

Comment: @user2007 Jazakallah Khair

Answer (score 1):

You are not obligated to since you're not a believer. But out of respect for our prophet (even if you don't believe in him) and for your Muslim readers (because some might take offense), it'd probably be better if you put "PBUH" after the Prophet's name :)